# How to get sum using filter aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I wanted to calculate the sum of total_stake which status does not Cancelled as per below mentioned table using elasticsearch. Please let me know whether my approach is correct or not. Please let me know your suggestions as well.

I tried the below aggregation filter which return me the sum of all total_stake.

```
SumAggregationBuilder sumOfTotalStake = AggregationBuilders.sum(TOTAL_STAKE).field(TOTAL_STAKE);
    BoolQueryBuilder bqb = boolQuery().mustNot(termQuery("state", "Cancelled"));

    // create the filter aggregation and add the sub-aggregation
    FilterAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.filter(TOTAL_STAKE+"New", bqb).subAggregation(sumOfTotalStake);
```

[image]

Comment: you might attract more suggestions if you post raw query as it will gain traction from variety of engineers familiar with ES rather than just the java tech stack

Comment: I'm using elastic library in spring boot application.